# Gaps and islands question - Grouping sequential runs of data to get max and min dates

Tags: oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a gaps-and-islands problem I haven't been able to solve using Oracle.

I'm trying to get the first and last event (`LOGIN_TIME`) in an unbroken series of `PC_ID` and `USER_NAME` having the same values. In this example, I want the `MIN(LOGIN_TIME)` and `MAX(LOGIN_TIME)`, but only in the first three logins before 'jane' logged in. Then, I want the same for 'jane', and so on.

Query

```
SELECT 
    PC_ID,
    USER_NAME,
    LOGIN_TIME
FROM
    LOGIN_AUDIT
WHERE PC_ID = 72
AND LOGIN_TIME BETWEEN '2020-08-10 00:00:00' AND '2020-08-18 00:00:00'
;
```

The output from the above query would look like this:

```
| PC_ID | USER_NAME | LOGIN_TIME          |
|-------|-----------|---------------------|
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-10 09:00:00 |
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-10 13:30:00 |
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-11 09:00:00 |
| 72    | jane      | 2020-08-12 08:00:00 |
| 72    | jane      | 2020-08-13 09:00:00 |
| 72    | jane      | 2020-08-13 14:30:00 |
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-14 08:00:00 |
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-15 08:00:00 |
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-16 08:00:00 |
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-17 08:00:00 |
```

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
| PC_ID | USER_NAME | FIRST_LOGIN         | LAST_LOGIN          |
|-------|-----------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-10 09:00:00 | 2020-08-11 09:00:00 |
| 72    | jane      | 2020-08-12 08:00:00 | 2020-08-13 14:30:00 |
| 72    | bob       | 2020-08-14 08:00:00 | 2020-08-17 08:00:00 |
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach for this type of gaps and islands problem is the difference in row numbers method.  Consider:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PC_ID ORDER BY LOGIN_TIME) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PC_ID, USER_NAME ORDER BY LOGIN_TIME) rn2
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    PC_ID,
    USER_NAME,
    MIN(LOGIN_TIME) AS FIRST_LOGIN,
    MAX(LOGIN_TIME) AS LAST_LOGIN
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    PC_ID,
    USER_NAME,
    (rn1 - rn2)
ORDER BY
    MIN(LOGIN_TIME);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo